# Flutter Webview Plugin embedded vimeo no fullscreen button on android but it has on ios

Tags: video, flutter, dart, webview

I used flutter_webview_plugin 0.3.8, I embedd vimeo player and played it on ios the fullscreen button shows up but not in android.

The website has iframe on it,

"<--iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/{video id here..}?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" width="100vh" height="100%" frameborder="0"  webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen>"

return WebviewScaffold(

```
url: widget.data.link,
withJavascript: true, 
withZoom: false,  
appBar: AppBar(
   title: Text(""),
   elevation: 1
),
initialChild: Container(
  color: Colors.white,
  child: const Center(
  child: SpinKitRing(
      color: Colors.black,
      size: 30.0,
      lineWidth: 2.0,
  ),
),)  );
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: unfortunately still little information on implementation of vimeo for flutter, I have already searched for something related is not successful.

Comment: In the case of Android, why not show a custom button below the WebView and open a new screen where you show the video in landscape mode in fullscreen?

Comment: Also, share your full code.

Comment: Hey..Did you get the answer for this?

Comment: Hi, if you are interested, I have made a plugin wrapping the vimeo player. https://github.com/ThuAbLKA/flutter-vimeo-player check it out!

Comment: @thusith.92 Bro, I think that the plugin would be even more helpful if you extended it to include a full-screen mode option.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried locally and it seems that this is actually [a bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27101).

Here is a sample running in the latest version [webview_flutter: ^2.0.12](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/versions/2.0.12) plugin.

Android:

[image]

iOS:

[image]

Sample code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Sample',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.teal,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Sample'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://vimeo.com/521802279',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted),
    );
  }
}
```